# php showing some kind of code instead of email body

Tags: php, email, imap

I am reading email body using IMAP and storing it in my database. I have display code where I am reading the email body from database and showing it on the webpage, but I get this message. Can someone assist me ? Looks like the database has this value when i initially read it from IMAP or is there a way I can convert it to meaning full data? Thank you.

"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAABeCAYAAACZ4CkLAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAAS dAAAEnQB3mYfeAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUATWljcm9zb2Z0IE9mZmljZX/tNXEAAG0ESURBVHhe 7b13k2TXde25y3tf7X032sET3hAkQS8aOYbeezMKUYoJad4o5q+................"

Comment: This is my code to read the value of the email body from database and showing it on the webpage.................................$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_read WHERE Mail_id = $id");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo quoted_printable_decode($row['Email_Body']);

Answer (score 0):

Decoding it from base 64 returns binnary data for a png file.

Comment: Hi there, It was not a PNG file, it was an email without any attachment or image, but yet the values are in this format. thanks